# Embedding .exe in html

Tags: html, executable, exe

I need help to embed a game into HTML, If I did replicate the game in html, it`s complicated so is there any code to do it?

PS: It has to be an element in the site not opened in a new window

Comment: What language are you using? If Java, you can do it, otherwise, an "exe" on a page is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely wild guess here, but if you made the game with Game Maker, there is [GameMaker:HTML5](http://yoyogames.com/) available, which allows you to take the same code as you wrote for the Windows EXE and export it to valid HTML5/JavaScript.

Aside from that, there is no way to embed an EXE into a webpage.

Answer (score 4):

You cant embed an exe in html. You can either rewrite the game in a web-friendly language such as javascript, flash, or java, or you can just make it be a downloaded game. If exes were allowed to run from webpages, viruses would be even more prevalent than they are now.